# When returning an ArrayList do I have to return the <Type> along with it?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, generic-programming

Specifically, if I return a filled `ArrayList` do I have to return the type with it such as `ArrayList<modNode>`? To add onto this, if i'm using a generic typing for a custom link list that uses the `<T>` tag would I have to return `ArrayList<modNode<T>>`? Just a little curious on the properties of ArrayLists containing generic objects... Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Can you offer an example of what you mean?

Comment: Can you please share the code and the problem you are facing?

Comment: If you turn on all compiler warnings, the compiler will tell you when you are improperly returning a raw type or any other unsafe type.  It’s good practice in general to turn on all the warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a method that returns an `ArrayList` of `String` objects:

```
public ArrayList<String> foo() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... fill list ...
    return list;
}
```

This is how you would normally<sup>1</sup> declare the method in Java 5+ (since the addition of generics). But you don't *have* to do this. You *could* declare the method as:

```
public ArrayList foo() {
    // ... code ...
    return list;
}
```

This would mean you are using [*raw types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Unless you are interacting with a legacy (pre Java 5) library/application you [never want to use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). The reason is because a raw type is (nearly?) equivalent to returning `ArrayList<Object>`. You've just lost all type safety given by generics. The reason for generics is to provide compile-time<sup>2</sup> type checks so you don't accidentally use the wrong types. For instance, you could now add a `Dog` to the `ArrayList` returned by `foo` even though you intended it to only contain `String` objects. Also, code using the returned `ArrayList` has no guarantee that there will only be `String` objects inside the `ArrayList` which can result in all sorts of headaches.

You could get around raw types by casting:

```
String element = (String) foo().get(0);
```

However, that's basically what generic code compiles down to anyway; except you no longer have compile-time safety.

If the element type is also generic then yes you would want to return that information as well. Let's say you return an `ArrayList` of `Supplier` objects instead. It will be each `Supplier` that returns the needed `String` objects.

```
public ArrayList<Supplier<String>> foo() {
    // ... code ...
}
```

It's important you give the `Supplier`'s generic signature here so you can do things like:

```
for (Supplier<String> sup : foo()) {
    String str = sup.get();
    // .. do something with "str" ...
}
```

If you returned `ArrayList<Supplier>` then each `Supplier.get()` would return an `Object`. You've lost all type safety again.

---

<sup>1. You would actually, in virtually all cases, want to return `List` rather than `ArrayList`. It's best to [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).</sup>

<sup>2. It only works at compile-time due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens).</sup>

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter `<T>` depends on the actual Type Parameter you supply to Generic Type. For example:-

```
   List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

`String` is the actual type parameter of parameterized type `List<String>`. Behind the scene compiler did casting on each elements automatically. So you can safely expect `get` method will return `String` type.

The `modNode` class is generic type. Then caller has to declare what is the actual type parameter. It could be `String`, type that extends `Node` or whatever. Example below:-

```
   List<modeNode<String>> modeNodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

However your `ArrayList<modNode<T>>` actual type parameter is already `modeNode`. Hence `get` method will probably returns some kind parameterized type `modeNode<T>`. Ex:-

```
   List<modeNode<String>> modeNodes = new ArrayList<>();
   ....
   modeNode<String> mn = modeNodes.get(0);
```

Notes:-

** Rename `modNode` type class name to `ModNode` to follow Java convention. Class name must start with Capital letter.

```
   ModeNode<Node> mn = ModeNode.getInstance();
   //More readable due to following naming convention.
   List<ModeNode<Node>> mns = new ArrayList<>();
```

** It is preferable to declare as interface type `List`than concrete type `ArrayList`. Unless if you want to use specific `ArrayList` behaviour implementation.